# KAFKA consumer setup behind a proxy on prem. Producer is in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, apache-kafka, consumer

We have a KAFKA setup in AWS and we publish message from the publisher there, we want to consume those messages through Kafka consumer from on-prem boxes which have access to the internet through a proxy. Is there any setup in the KAFKA consumer so that we can update the proxy detail.

Note: We are able to connect and get a message from a local box (Kafka consumer) which has direct access to the internet (without proxy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `advertised.listeners` to the external IP so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they'll try to connect to the internal IP (since `advertised.listeners` will default to `listeners` unless explicitly set)

Ref: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: Thank you for the information. However here I am asking about the client who is behind a firewall  and trying to connect to a topic in the AWS which is open for the client.